# mysql: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, sockets

I got an error after loading new data to mysql. 
Basically, I used something like `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.sql` to export data from my last DB.
Then I use `mysql -u root -p` ... then `\. malldb.sql`.
when I restart my system I can not connect to DB anymore.
I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/705466/600715) 
then I got this :

```
user@user $ mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
2017-05-29T08:41:32.336559Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-05-29T08:41:32.343064Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for 

UNIX socket file don't exists.

[1]+  Exit 1                  mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

then

```
user@user$ : mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I think the diagnostic of this answer is correct, but still unable to understand why it not working.
can someone help?

**Update** 
when I use :

```
`user@user# /etc/init.d/mysql start`
    [ ok ] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

then :

```
user@user# mysql -uroot -p
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded
```

Comment: Looks like the mysql Server is not started

Comment: @Jens thank for your comment, but Even when I restart I got almost the same error.

Comment: How do you start the mysql Server?

Comment: @Jens /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: if you use `ps -ef |grep mysql` you see the mysql process running?

Comment: I got this : `mysql     7812     1  0 10:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      7933  3975  0 11:04 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
`

Comment: Can you try to kill this process and restart it

Comment: I used : `sudo kill -9 7812` and `/etc/init.d/mysql start` and I am still having the exact same error. when `mysql -u root -p`